# NPM NPX cannot run scripts post version 6

Tags: javascript, npm, npx

Recently upgraded NPM from 6.x to 8.x, and our package script is no longer accessible via npx.

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "npx run-p lint:js lint:css",
  "lint:css": "npx stylelint 'src/**/*.{css,scss,vue}'",
  "lint:js": "npx eslint --max-warnings 0 --ext .html,.js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"
}
```

`npm run lint` now fails with

```
Starting: lint:js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/.../Projects/cmi-radar/lint:css'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove all the `npx` prefixes? e.g. `"lint": "run-p lint:js lint:css"`, and then `npm run lint`.

Comment: It does, along with the other npx references in `lint:css` and `lint:js` --is that new?

Comment: No idea. All I know is that's how it works on my machine. Basically `npm` looks for the `.bin/[package]/[exe file]` in `node_modules` and then runs it.

Comment: Which is why this was failing, as npm should look for the script, not the executable. Removing the npx allows it to do that...odd